# can bash "source" a custom-interpreter shell?

Tags: bash

it is well known that bash will execute a "script" with a non-bash
interpreter in the she-bang line (e.g. like "#! /bin/cat")

what seem not to work though (at least at 1st try), is including such 
custom-interpreted scripts in proper bash scripts, using the source or 
the dot commands, i.e. 
something like

```
#! /bin/bash; echo these are the terms; source terms.cat
```

with `terms.cat` interpreter being `#! /bin/cat`

Has anyone found a way to do something similar (or is sure
it cannot be done?)

(please don't answer me how to solve the contrived example; I know 
how; my real situation is a lot more complex; the example just 
conveys the idea)

Answer (score 2):

The `source` command is explicitly meant to load scripts *as if they were part of the main script.* Think of it as C `#include` or PHP `require()`.

This means that the contents of that file must also be a valid bash script. Bash will neither care about `#!` headers nor ask the kernel to care about them; it'll just read the file directly and skip over those as if they were regular comments.

In other words, if you want the #! line to be honored, your main script will have to directly execute that file as a command.

*(Or tell `perl` to execute it. Perl tries to be helpful and spawns the correct interpreter for you.)*

Comment: thanks grawity for sharing it. It is strange though that while bash will "eval" one-liners, there is no some "source" variant that instead of including a regular file, it would write-in the bash-valid-syntax output of another cmd (because it boils down to this)

Comment: Well, if that's what you want, you can `eval "$(command)"` or `source <(command)` ... or rethink your approach to programming.